How to find Windows Version like " 22H2 "
I want to find Windows Version like 22H2 in a domain via PowerShell for multiable pc remotely
And I have the below command, and it's working in my pc but I want to use it in a multiable pc remotely
(Get-Item "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue('DisplayVersion')
when i do below command i get the error in pic
DInvoke-Command `
  -ComputerName C0000255 `
  -ScriptBlock {
    (Get-Item 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').GetValue('DisplayVersion')
  }



Just read up on using Invoke-Command
Invoke-Command `
  -ComputerName host1, host2, host3, etc. `
  -ScriptBlock {
    (Get-Item 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').GetValue('DisplayVersion')
  }


I did your command but not working

So what is the error?

From the error you have, it is not an error of Invoke-Command. It seems more likely be a communication error between your computer and the remote one named C0000255.
Multiple factors can result in having this message :

I would make sure the DNS name is correct and communication to this computer is possible, with simply running the command "ping C0000255"

If this works, from a RDP session on the C0000255 :

Check if the firewall is allowing WinRM, there should be rules named Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In) allowed in your Inbound rules
Make sure WinRM service is running with the PS command "get-service WinRM"
From an elevated Powershell prompt, verify your WinRM configuration with "winrm get winrm/config"
Make sure the ports 5985 or/and 5986 are in "listening" state by running "netstat -an", generally, there should be entries like "0.0.0.0:5985" or "0.0.0.0:5986"
Check the SPN configuration with the command "setspn -L C0000255", you should have entries starting with "WSMAN"

